# PHP For Loop through date range not working

Tags: php, mysql, for-loop

I'm trying to loop through every day in a month and get the number of results for each day in one month.

I've done the following;

```
<?php
include 'inclues/db.inc.php';

for($i = 2; $i < 30; $i++){
    $date2 = $i-1;
    $date1 = $i;

    $q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `date` < '2012-09-".$date1." 00:00:00' AND `date` > '2012-09-".$date2." 00:00:00'";
    //$r = mysql_fetch_assoc($q);
    echo mysql_num_rows($q)."<br />";
}

?>
```

It works if I just try to echo out dates 1 and 2 but not if I use the query.. I end up with a 500 internal server error when using the query.

Any ideas on how to resolve this? Is it generally bad practice to use a query within a loop?

Comment: you have a missing `)` at the end of the line of your mysql_query

Comment: I need to change my settings to show errors rather than giving me a 500 internal server error. I'll try that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just execute

`SELECT date, COUNT(*) from table group by date`

Comment: well, you'll probably need to do some date_trunc on the date. I'm more used to Postgresql, but a function like that would exist for mysql too

Comment: @user410932 I don't think you'd need to do anything more - Gedrox's query will do what you are doing without all the extra php

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `date` BETWEEN $date1 AND $date2;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not bad practice to use a query within a loop.

Check what your query-string is becomming, try running that query manually on your db. It probably produses some error.

```
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `date` < '2012-09-".$date1." 00:00:00' AND `date` >      '2012-09-".$date2." 00:00:00'";
 echo $sql;
 $q = mysql_query($sql);
```